# Turning off auto-complete for text fields in Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox

Am supposed to be learning French at the moment, but rather than learning any vocab, I've been mucking around with a rails app that tests vocab - so it displays a word, and I have to type its translation.

Unfortunately, Firefox remembers everything I've already type there, so which diminishes its usefulness somewhat.

Is it possible, through the options for form_for or otherwise, to turn this normally useful behaviour off?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

So it turns out it's pretty simple.  Rather than

```
<%= f.text_field :fieldname %>
```

put

```
<%= f.text_field :fieldname, :autocomplete => :off %>
```

Answer (score 35):

You can also turn off autocomplete at the form level by using the :autocomplete attribute in the :html collection, which will generate the HTML that Erv referenced.  The syntax is

```
<% form_for :form_name, @form_name, :html => {:autocomplete => "off"} do |f|%>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks your was life saver (whew). but it only turned off autocomplete for first text box within the form!!!

Comment: Thanks for this. It worked when setting autocomplete to "off" on each individual input didn't.

Answer (score 8):

Add autocomplete="off" as an attibute on your form tag:

```
<form action="..." method="..." autocomplete="off" >
</form>
```

Comment: this is what the raw HTML would look like, but it would be better to do it through rails itself...

Answer (score 7):

I was using the "tag" variant of forms and found this to work:

```
<%= text_field_tag('favorite animal', nil, :options => {:autocomplete => 'off'}) %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Below the tag variant **for Rails 3** applications:

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, nil, :autocomplete => 'off' %>
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in Rails 4+

```
<%= f.text_field :name, autocomplete: :off %>
```

Nice and simple

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution for me in Rails 4+

In the form i added:

```
:autocomplete => "off"
```

And in the field:

```
:autocomplete=>"none"
```

Example:

```
  <%= form_for(@user.address_detail,
           :url => {:action => :update_address},
           :validate => true,
           :method => :put,
           :html => {:class => "form-horizontal",:autocomplete => "off"},
  ) do |f| %>

          <div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_field :address_line_1,:autocomplete=>"none" %>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use simple_form_for you can use autocomplete also bur only with input_html if you use it on a specific field.

For example :

```
    <%= f.input :password, input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
```